# How to change layout for a full page render inline livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I would like to use an inline livewire component for guest and app pages. By default, I understand that livewire reverts back to `layout.app` and I know you can update the default layout for all full page renders.

I am reading this docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components and was able to get it working with regular approach of just having  `blade` and `.PHP` file.

```
public function render()
    {
        return <<<'HTML'
            <div>
                example page view
            </div>
        HTML;
    }
```

Is it possible to do this thing from the docs in an inline component where we return the HTML directly?

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-posts')
            ->layout('layouts.guest');
    }

public function render()
    {
        return <<<'HTML'
            <div>
                example page view
            </div>
        HTML; ->layout('layouts.guest'); // something along the lines of this
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. You have to use view()->layout() arrow function

Comment: i understand i cant use arrow function, I am asking if there is some other way to structure the render method to allow for switching of default

Comment: so that is has the same effect as being able to do `view()->layout()`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use it this way:

```
public function render()
    {
        $datas = [
            'data' => 'example page view'
        ];
        
        return view('livewire.show-posts', $data)
            ->layout('layouts.guest');
    }
```

Comment: I dont have a view blade file called `show-posts`  I am using an inline livewire component so there is only 1 file